# Linux networking + mix of auto-negotiation of yes/no

Tags: switch, network, networking, linux, network-access

we have 10 servers with  `Advertised auto-negotiation: yes`

as

**the machines with driver driver: i40e**

```
driver: i40e
version: 2.3.2-k
firmware-version: 10.51.5
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:12:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes


Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
Supported link modes:   10000baseSR/Full
Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Supported FEC modes: Not reported
Advertised link modes:  10000baseSR/Full
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Speed: 10000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: FIBRE
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: off
Supports Wake-on: d
Wake-on: d
Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                       drv probe link
Link detected: yes
```

and we have another 10  servers with  `Advertised auto-negotiation: no

**the machines with driver: ixgbe**

```
driver: ixgbe
version: 4.4.0-k-rh7.3
firmware-version: 0x8000091d
bus-info: 0000:0b:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no


      Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: No
Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: No
Speed: 10000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: FIBRE
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: external
Auto-negotiation: off
Supports Wake-on: d
Wake-on: d
Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                       drv probe link
Link detected: yes
```

regarding to mix of auto-negotiation

is that can be a problem when both group of servers are commentated between them?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Comment: What NIC and driver? Technically, 1G+ require auto-negotiation. I'm a bit puzzled by the driver saying it's not supported. (yes, I've run into carrier ethernet circuits that had to have auto-neg disabled to work, but I'd call those pseudo-ethernet)

Comment: on the first machine the driver is driver: ixgbe

Comment: on the other machines the driver is driver: i40e

Comment: I update the Question

Answer (score 1):

In theory, No, since 10Gb Ethernet only works at full duplex.  But as a general rule, you should set all your devices to auto-negotiation.  It's also a good idea to make your devices as uniform as possible to simplify management.

Comment: so how to know if this is a problem of switch or linux machines?

Comment: As I said, 10G only works at full duplex, so there is no other option.

Comment: I mean if we want to disabled it , what is the procedure to know if switch is enabled it or maybe this should be on linux machines as conf under /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts

Comment: What kind of switch?

Comment: juniper switch ( we also configured vlan )

Comment: another thing all network is jumbo frame MTU=9000

Comment: The switch has auto-negotiation enabled, but for 10G, there is only full duplex.  All devices on the same VALN should have the same MTU.  Otherwise you will drop packets.

Comment: so in that case we need to set the auto neg to false , then the question is , this should be from linux side or from switch side?

Comment: The switch and the computer **must** match.  Set the negotiation to auto on all devices.

Comment: can I ask how to verify on juniper how to verify the auto neg staus?

Comment: but if we enable auto neg on switch you can see also from my Question that Supports auto-negotiation is NO on the other servers from ethtool

Comment: If you can't change your servers, then don't worry about it. You can type `show interfaces <interface name>` on the switch.

Comment: we see that auto neg is off , so do you recommended to set is as true?

Comment: I'm not expert at Juniper.  You may not be able to change it.

Comment: on other case I dont understand why ethtool show diff in case switch is  show false